# Angular2 page rendering

Tags: html, angular

How is the page in the Angular2 is rendered? Does it render all the DOM elements that might be used at the page, for example pop-up, dialog? Or does it render after the element is being invoked?

Answer (score 1):

For angular 2 when you spin up a server it loads all the html templates lazily. The `index.html` page is the entry point and by default the `app-root` directive is loaded first. If you have say another component `featureA` and `featureB` that are triggered by clicking a button or some other UI element those aren't loaded until you actually click on it.